# how to update table from an external table

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to update a employee table based on my external table, but I got ORA-01427 error,
single-row subquery returns more than one row

```
employee(emp_id, emp_name, job_history, city_code)
ext_table(emp_name, job_history, city_name)
city(city_code, city_name)
```

data in my ext_table as following:

```
Sandy, waitress, los angeles
Sandy, restaurant manager, los angeles
John, store manager, phoenix

update employee em
set (em.emp_name, em.job_history, em.city_code) = 
    (select t.emp_name, t.job_history, t.city_code
     from (select distinct(emp_name), job_history, c.city_code from 
           ext_table e, city c where e.city_name=c.city_name) t) 
    where em.emp_name=t.emp_name;
```

I am greatly appreciate for any help

Answer (score 1):

This is what `MERGE` is for:

```
merge into employee 
using
(
  select e.emp_name, e.job_history, c.city_code 
  from ext_table e 
    join city c on e.city_name=c.city_name
) t on (t.emp_name = employee.emp_name)
when matched then update
  set job_history = t.job_history, 
      city_code = t.city_code;
```

Note that it's useless to update `emp_name` as that is the column you use to join between `ext_table` and `employee`.

The above assumes that emp_name is unique in `ext_table` (and employee). If this is not the case you will need to find some "key" that uniquely identifies the employee in the external table.

Also: `distinct` is ***NOT*** a function.

`select distinct (foo), bar` is absolutely identical to `select distinct foo, bar`. It always operates on **all** columns. The difference between the two is the same as the difference between `select (foo),bar` and `select foo, bar`.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible option is to convert external table to regular table and update. To convert external to regular table use SQL Developer. Steps: 1.Create empty table with the same structure as your external table. 2.Export data from external to reg. table. The process is similar to exporting data from file to Excel.

Answer (score -2):

you can do it by using update query with join . check following code

> UPDATE employee  SET  job_history = B.job_history ,   city_code =
>   C.city_code  FROM EMPLOYEE as A   INNER JOIN ext_table AS B ON
>   A.emp_name = B.emp_name  INNER JOIN city AS C ON B.city_name =
>   C.city_name

Comment: That is not valid for Oracle.